# Study of an implicit function

Tags: calculus, implicit-function

The problem consists of two questions :

The first asks to prove that for any real number $x$, there exists a unique real numbers $t$ such that 
$$t_x^3x^2+t_x+x=0$$

I'm having problems with the second question which asks to **study the implicit function** $f:x\longmapsto t_x$

A **hint** asked to **study the inverse function** of $f$ but I'm having a hard time to prove that $f$ is invertible, let alone to study its inverse.

**What I could do :**

- $f(x)$ and $x$ have opposite signs due to the equation $t_x(x^2t_x^2+1)=-x$
- seeing the equation as a quadratic in $x$, the discriminant should be $\ge 0$ meaning range of $f$ is within $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right]$
- if $f$ is invertible the inverse has one of the expressions 
  $\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4t^4}}{2t^3}$ (got by solving $(g(y))^2y^3+g(y)+y=0$)
- A few tests on wolframalpha show that $f$ would be odd, negative and decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$.

Any help or recommendations to treat such problems would be appreciated.

Comment: But the fact that for any $x$ there exists a unique $t$ doesn't mean that $x \mapsto t_x $ is injective. 
Regarding the question; the original problem is that "vague".
It asks the "study" of the function, that might include limits, continuity, monotonicity, and maybe other more features of $f$.